# Ios:Delegete method does not called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, xcode7

I'm trying to call a delegate method but isn't working. Where is my mistake?

Here is the class where i have declared @protocol, delegate and the method:

```
#import "EEBaseVC.h"

@protocol EEInterstitialScreenDelegete;

@interface EEInterstitialScreen : EEBaseVC

@property(nonatomic,strong) id <EEInterstitialScreenDelegete> delegete;

@end

@protocol EEInterstitialScreenDelegete <NSObject>

-(void)interstitialScreenUpdateInfo:(EEInterstitialScreen *)interstitialscreen;

@end
```

And this is the declaration of the delegate method in another ViewController:

```
#pragma mark - EEInterstitialScreenDelegate

-(void)interstitialScreenUpdateInfo:(EEInterstitialScreen *)interstitialscreen
{
   NSLog("hello");
}
```

I have to do some stuff to call this method in the previous view controller. But the if condition is not satisfied:

```
if (_delegete && [_delegete respondsToSelector:@selector(interstitialScreenUpdateInfo:)] ) {
    [_delegete interstitialScreenUpdateInfo:self];
}
```

Comment: Do you actually set the delegate? Does the delegate have a strong reference to it somewhere?

Comment: yes i have already set delegete, where i have declared method.

Comment: Did u set the the `target.delegate = self` (target = EEInterstitialScreen instance) in the another ViewController? Ppl ussually running to issue coz forgetting this

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the "if" and see what goes wrong. My guess is that _delegete is nil.

Comment: yes i have settled like
EEInterstitialScreen*is=[[EEInterstitialScreen alloc]init];
 is.delegete=self;

Comment: @Eiko:yes you right , _delegete is nil, but why that i dont know, wolud you please give me solution.

Comment: @iketan Impossible to say without seing the code. Again the question: is there a strong reference to your delegate? (BTW: time to fix that "delegete" spelling ;)

Comment: yes  i have settled it to (nonatomic,strong) but still it is returning null.and thanks for suggesting about spelling mistake.And please tell me which part of code you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
AnotherViewController * obj = [AnotherViewController alloc]init];
obj.delegate =self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj];
```